# where should I insert `os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"`?

Tags: python, numpy, ray

According to [this document](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-rl-pong.html?highlight=openblas), I have to insert `os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"` to prevent `numpy` from using more than one core. But where should I insert this? before `numpy` or in each actor's construction? Should it be used in the `Learner`?

For example, where should I insert it if I have the following three files?

```py
""" learner.py """
import numpy as np
import ray

@ray.remote
class Learner:
    def __init__(self):
        # do something
```

```py
""" worker.py """
import numpy as np
import ray

@ray.remote
class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        # do something
```

```py
""" main.py """
# program starts from here

import numpy as np
import ray

from learner import Learner
from worker import Worker

ray.init()

learner = Learner.remote()
worker = Worker.remote()

# do something...
```

How can I check if it works as expected?
Here's a snapshot of `top` from my real project, where I insert `os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"` at the beginning of `main.py`. Does it work?
[image]

Comment: you can add at the beginning after `import os` on your main file.

Comment: Thanks for answering. May I ask how to know if it works correctly?

Comment: You might achieve more dynamic and fine-grained control using https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's working by looking in `top` and making sure that none of the worker process CPU utilizations exceed 100%.

You want to set this before you call `ray.init()` so that when the worker processes are forked, the environment variable propagates to them.

You can achieve the same thing by starting your Python script with `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1 python script.py`.

Note that this environment variable makes sense when `numpy` uses MKL, but depending on the BLAS implementation you might need to set an environment variable like `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` or `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I never spot any worker process CPU utilization exceeds 100%, no matter whether I set `MKL_NUM_THREADS`(or OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS) or not. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the Lock I used in replay buffer?

Comment: In that case, it's probably unnecessary to use `MKL_NUM_THREADS`. Perhaps `numpy` is already only using one thread. You can test this by running something like `import numpy as np; x = np.zeros((7000, 7000)); np.dot(x, x)` and seeing if CPU utilization goes over 100%.

Comment: The point of using that environment variable is to prevent multiple Ray workers from all running multithreaded numpy functions that each try to use all of the CPU resources on the machine.

Comment: I get the point of why the instruction tells us to do this. But I've done some test and cannot really see the performance gain of doing so.

Comment: If numpy is already only using a single thread, then there will be no change in behavior. The difference will be apparent if you are trying to run a bunch of parallel numpy operations and each operation attempts to use multiple threads.

Comment: Hi @Robert Nishihara. I run my code on atari, spotting that all workers use about 101~102% CPU, I've set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`(I figured that numpy installed by `pip` uses OPENBLAS) beforehand, and set `inter_op_parallelism_threads=1` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads=1` in `tf.ConfigProto`. Does this suggest any problem?